# How to populate the select list by jquery ajax in cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I am using cakephp, and i want to get the selected degree id and want to display subjects belongs to the selected degree in another drop down list. My degree select list is below

```
<div class="form-group">
  <?php echo $this->Form->input('PrimaryRegister.degree', array(
     'options'=>$degrees,
     'empty'=>'-- select one --',
     'label' => false, 
     'class' => 'form-control',
     'id' => 'degree',
     'required'=>'required')
   ); ?>
</div>
```

and My jquery is below

```
$('#degree').change(function(){
    var degree_id=$(this).val();
    var base_url='<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>';
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        data:'degree_id='+degree_id,
        dataType:'json',
        url:base_url+'/pages/bla',
        async:false,
        success: function(data){
            $(data).each(function() {
             $('.test').append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
            });
        }
    })
});
```

the result I want display into is below

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label>Main/Core<sup class="madadatory">*</sup></label>
                            <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input('PrimaryRegister.MainSubject1',array(
     'label'=>false,
     'options'=>'',
     'empty'=>'-- select one --',
     'class'=>'form-control test',
     'id'=>'MainSubject1',
     'required'=>'required'
             )
          );
       ?>
</div>
```

Note: I am getting the array as ajax result, that is below

```
<pre>Array
(
[1] => Zoology 
[2] => Botany 
[3] => Plant Science 
[4] => Home Science 
[5] => Forestry 
[6] => Microbiology 
[7] => Chemistry 
[8] => Polymer Chemistry 
[9] => Biochemistry 
[10] => Biotechnology 
[11] => Physics 
[12] => Psychology 
[13] => Geology 
[14] => Mathematics 
[15] => Computer Science 
[16] => Electronics 
[17] => Geography 
[18] => Statistics
[19] => Bioinformatics
[20] => Electronics & Communication 
[21] => Acqua Culture and Fishery Microbiology?
[22] => Applied Statistics
[23] => Applied Physics
[24] => Chemistry
[25] => Botany
[26] => Costume and Fashion Technology
[27] => Counselling Psychology
[28] => Genetics
[29] => Environmental Science and Water Management
[30] => Family and Community Science
[31] => Food Technology
)
```

The subject selecting field is generating by jquery only, please help me

Comment: my problem is i want to place the result array into the subject select list

Comment: modify your controller action to response in json instead of array using built in json view. this way it will be easier to process with jquery.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can generate the `html string` in the view after fetching them in the action and print the string on the view of the action.

```
public function your_function() {
    // fetch the data
    // set the array for view
}
```

On the view

```
foreach($your_array as $key => $value) {
   echo "<option value='$key'>$value</option>;
}
```

The ajax will get this html as the response. And then set the html -

```
$('.your_drop_down_menu').html(response);
```

Comment: That can be done. but i want to supply this array to many other select fields also, whose name will be differed.

Comment: Then use `class` as `selector` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you want to populate a `select` tag you reference the whole tag with value and text.

```
$(data).each(function () {
    $("<option value='" + yourValue + "'>" + yourText + "</option>").appendTo('.test');
});
```